# Redraw dataTable after updated through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I'm using dataTable and boostrap modal.

Trough the bootstrap modal, I update a row with AJAX in my database, all is OK, but when I close the bootstrap modal (contening the update form), I would like to redraw the updated row without reloading the page.

[image]

The problem is that I'm using a bootstrap modal and my dataTable is outside this modal (the modal has the focus)

[image]

I tried this code :

```
success:function(result)
{                
   table
   .row( $(this).parents('tr'))
   .draw();
}
```

table is

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

**The problem is that my modal has the focus...**

Comment: Another solution is by using datatables [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Comment: The modal should have a `close` event, you can simply call `table.draw()` from that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark, I have this code $('#squarespaceModalupdatecategorie').on('hidden.bs.modal', function ()
        {
            table.draw();
         });  but no redraw...